# Showing $\kappa^{cf(\kappa)}$ determines the map $\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be a limit cardinal. I want to show

1) If $2^\alpha$ is eventually constant as $\alpha\rightarrow\kappa$, then $2^\kappa=2^{<\kappa}\cdot\kappa^{cf(\kappa)}$.

2) If $2^\alpha$ is not constant as $\alpha\rightarrow\kappa$, $2^\kappa=\lambda^{cf(\lambda)}$ where $\lambda=2^{<\kappa}$

Here $2^{<\kappa}$ denotes $\sum_{\alpha<\kappa}2^\alpha$. (Also, is $\sum_{\alpha<\kappa}2^\alpha=\sum_{\alpha<cf(\kappa)}2^\alpha$ here or not?) For part 1) I think that if $2^\alpha$ is eventually constant as $\alpha\rightarrow\kappa$, then $2^\kappa$ is that constant value, but I don't know where to go from there. If $\kappa$ is singular then $\kappa=\sum_{\nu<cf(\kappa)}\kappa_\nu$ with $\kappa_\nu<\kappa$, but I'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would $\sum_{\alpha<\kappa}2^\alpha=\sum_{\alpha<\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}2^\alpha$? Better yet, you should find out when these two expressions coincide.

Comment: Can I think of it as: $2^{<\kappa}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}2^\alpha=2^\kappa=\sum_{\nu<cf(\kappa)}2^{\kappa_\nu}$, where the second equality follows from the fact that $2^\alpha$ is not eventually constant?

Comment: How you conclude your second equality? Also, I do not see why you are assuming that $\alpha\mapsto 2^\alpha$ is not eventually constant.

Comment: I was wondering if $2^{<\kappa}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}2^\alpha=2^\kappa=\sum_{\nu<cf(\kappa)}2^{\kappa_\nu}$ would hold in the case (part 2 of my question) that $2^\alpha$ is not eventually constant.
I think the second equality follows since $\kappa$ is a limit ordinal and $2^\alpha$ never equals $2^\kappa$ - is that correct or not?

Comment: I do not understand your reasoning. How precisely do you conclude from the facts that $\kappa$ is a limit *cardinal* and that $2^\alpha\ne 2^\kappa$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$ that $\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}2^\alpha=2^\kappa$?